# Передача двоичного файла в SOAP запросе jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter

Задача - проверить, как выдерживает нагрузку SOAP сервис по проверке ЭЦП.

Запрос передает 2 аттачмента:

1) файл для проверки;
2) отсоединенную ЭЦП;

и то и то - двоичные файлы.

Второй день бьюсь как рыба об лед - в *soapUI* собрал запрос, ответ на него корректный.

Дальше в *jmeter* включаю прокси с записью запросов, посылаю запрос через эту проксю, ответ приходит также корректный.

А когда пытаюсь выполнить записанный проксей запрос - в ответ приходит ошибка обработки сертификата. 
Причем, в зависимости от выставленной в *HTTP Request* кодировке ошибка варьируется: либо "неожиданный конец данных в ASN1", либо "неверное значение данных в ASN1".

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
PS теоретически в jmeter есть плагин Custom SOAP Sampler, позволяющий прикреплять файлы, но при попытке им воспользоваться, какие бы данные/файлы я не пытался скормить, получаю ошибку "Error saving multipart message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос ещё актуален, то постараюсь ответить на него.

Для задачи отправки бинарных данных, а именно, бинарных запросов больших объёмов, успешно использовал два варианта:

### RawRequest

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/

1. Используя прокси-сервер, такой как Fiddler 4, записывается корректный HTTP-запрос от клиента, например, SOAP UI к серверу.
2. Тело запроса сохраняется в виде файла, полностью. Получается файл, в начале которого идёт заголовок HTTP-запроса, с указанием HOST, версии HTTP-протокола, другими полями HTTP HEADERS, а потом тело запроса.
3. Сохранённый HTTP Request открывается в текстовом редакторе и из него удаляется начало запроса, с указанием адреса страницы.
4. Удалённое начало запроса вставляется как текст в поле редактирования RawRequest. Нужные части заменяются на переменные ${domain} или ${soap_server_url}, чтобы запрос перестал зависеть от адреса конкретного узла, который использовался при записи эталонного запроса. Если это не критично, то можно и не делать.
5. Важно, поменять версию протокола на HTTP 1.0 и из заголовков убрать keep alive, сделать Connection: close, как на скриншоте в https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/ потому что RawRequest не поддерживает Keep Alive, в отличие от HTTP Request и будет завершать выполнение только когда сервер закроет соединение. А если сказать серверу, что клиент работает по HTTP 1.1 и поддерживает keep alive, то сервер поверит и будет держать соедиение открытым до наступления таймаута. В результате длительность ответов в логах jmeter будет завышена.
6. Важно указать, что клиент не поддерживает gzip и другое сжатие ответа на запрос. Так как RawRequest их и правда не поддерживает. Поэтому если надо ответ на запрос обработать POST-процессором, то придётся выставить заголовки так, чтобы ответ пришел сразу разжатым. Тогда можно будет легко парсить ответы, как текст, но это сильнее нагружает сетевой канал, и снимает операции по сжатию ответов с сервера приложений или реверс-прокси между клиентом и сервером. Важно понимать, что реальные клиенты будут поддерживать gzip и сервер будет упаковывать ответы в gzip. Если не удалить из заголовков поддержку gzip, то придётся разжимать ответы и только потом парсить - придётся чуть-чуть попрограммировать.
7. В поле Send File указывается имя файла, остатка файла с телом запроса.

В результате RawRequest поступает так - начало запроса (заголовки) формируются на основе того, что введено в поле редактирования, а конец запроса, включая тело, читается из файла. Комбинация этого даёт возможность отправлять любые данные очень точно.

Галочку Parse as HTTP ставить можно, если ответ приходит без gzip. Если приходит в gzip, и галочка стоит, то распарсить ответ как HTTP данный Sampler не сможет.

### OS_Process_Sampler

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler

Если же надо отправлять то же самое - запросы из файла, но с поддержкой HTTP 1.1 и другими хитрыми вещами. И не нужно обрабатывать ответы в Post Processor. То можно воспользоваться консольными утилитами wget или curl. Написать bat/sh-файл, отправляющий запросы, и вызывать его через OS Process Sampler.

Точнее не так. Если сценарий предполагает скачивание больших объёмов данных - тех же бинарных документов и подписей к ним. То у всех стандартных Sampler-ов таких как HTTP Request, Raw Request, TCP Sampler будет неизбежный жор памяти во время скачивания ответа на запрос. А у утилит wget или curl не будет жора памяти, они будут читать ответ и писать его в файл на диске.

Пример командного файла `wget-download.gzip.head.bat`, для **скачивания** больших ответов, с поддержкой gzip, Keep Alive и возвратом к JMeter первых 1024-байт ответа от сервера (чтобы ошибки логировать и обрабатывать хоть что-то).

```bash
@title %~nx0
@pushd %~dp0
@rem 100 MBit/sec
@rem --progress=dot:default (  1 KByte per line)
@rem --progress=dot:binary  (384 KByte per line)
@rem --progress=dot:mega    (  3 MByte per line)
@rem @echo Start: %DATE%  %TIME% >> wget.start.stop.log
D:\tools\cygwin\bin\wget.exe -S --limit-rate=20m --progress=dot:mega ^
    --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0" ^
    --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" ^
    --header "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" ^
    --header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" ^
    --output-document=- %1 | %~dp0head\bin\head.exe -c 1234 | %~dp0head\bin\gzip.exe -d -c -
@rem @echo Stop : %DATE%  %TIME% >> wget.start.stop.log
@popd
```

### Резюме

Таким образом. Чтобы отправить разные бинарные данные, в том числе и большие. Удобно использовать RawRequest, читая запрос из файла, который готовится на основе запроса, перехваченного Fiddler-ом.
А чтобы скачивать разные бинарные данные, в том числе и большие, удобно использовать OS Process Sampler и консольные утилиты wget или curl.

Также недавно сделал эксперимент с формированием тела запроса, используя возможности Groovy template engine, это удобный способ формирования сложных XML-документов, через JSR-223 Pre Processor в переменную. С последующим использованием переменной в качестве тела запроса в HTTP Request.